# Phpstorm - is it possible to do mass replacing over multiple files?

Tags: phpstorm

There's a great function in dreamweaver that lets you perform search/replace over multiple files or folders. I was wondering if that can be done with phpstorm as well?

Comment: What about multi line searches? Only seems to work with strings on one line for me!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Right click on any folder (or project root) and select `Replace in path` option.

Comment: Agreed. One of the best IDE available, IMHO.

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts for these purposes are: 'Find in path..' - Ctrl+Shift+F and for 'Replace in path..' - Ctrl+Shift+R.

Comment: NOTE: There is no way to undo this short of version control; if you find in path + Replace, you cannot cntrl+shift+z your changes.

Comment: @Kaylined unsure if this was changed, but I am able to undo find/replaces via ctrl+z.